# Where can I find detailed information of famous quant companies such as Renaissance Technologies?

Tags: finance, quantitative, quants, soft-question

I am doing a report about famous quant companies such as Renaissance Technologies. Where can I find information such as ranking of these companies and their fund's rate of return.

Answer (score 7):

Most RIAs have to file a Form ADV, through which some information is publicly available via [SEC's website](https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/firm/summary/106661).

Further, large RIAs are sometimes involved in high profile civil lawsuits through which information, e.g. revealed by current or former employees in the discovery process, becomes accessible in the form of public court filings. This would be available through the [PACER](https://pacer.uscourts.gov/) system.

Answer (score 4):

For Rentech, try the Greg Zuckerman book, "The Man Who Solved the Market: How Jim Simons Launched the Quant Revolution".

HSBC Hedge Fund Report might be of use for other funds.